# Como utilizar traduções em Qt diretamente com QApplication::tr()

Tags: c++, qt, localização

Em uma aplicação desenvolvida em Qt eu tenho uma classe não visual (isto é, que não é herdada de um `QWidget`) mas que manipula strings de texto que devem ser apresentadas ao usuário. Para utilizar o mecanismo de tradução do Qt, eu defini todas as strings utilizando a função `QApplication::tr()`.

As strings são corretamente exibidas na ferramenta `Linguist`, sob o contexto de `QApplication` (como esperado - veja imagem abaixo). Porém, quando via código eu altero o `Locale` da aplicação, apenas as strings sob o contexto de `MainWindow` são alteradas.

[image: Tela da ferramenta Linguist]

O código que eu utilizo para trocar o idioma é o seguinte:

```cpp
void MainWindow::setLocale(QString sLocale)
{
    QTranslator *pTranslator = m_mpTranslators[sLocale];
    if(pTranslator)
    {
        for(map<QString, QTranslator*>::iterator it = m_mpTranslators.begin(); it != m_mpTranslators.end(); ++it)
        {
            qApp->removeTranslator(it->second);
            QApplication::removeTranslator(it->second); // Essa linha não existia antes!
        }
        qApp->installTranslator(pTranslator);
        QApplication::installTranslator(pTranslator);  // Essa linha também não!

        if(sLocale == "pt_BR")
            m_pLocaleButton->menuAction()->setIcon(QIcon(":/resources/icons/pt_BR"));
        else
            m_pLocaleButton->menuAction()->setIcon(QIcon(":/resources/icons/en_UK"));

        ui->retranslateUi(this);
        updateUI();
    }
}
```

Creio que é importante notar que a alteração dos textos na interface gráfica é imediata (via chamadas de `ui->retranslateUi(this)` e `updateUI()`), mas que as chamadas da classe não visual **ocorrem posteriormente a troca do locale**, então o texto deveria ser traduzido corretamente.

No código acima, eu também cheguei a incluir as linhas marcadas com comentários, mas isso não fez com que a tradução acompanhasse o locale definido.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de onde eu possa estar me equivocando?

**Edição:**

A versão do Qt é a 5.1.0 (32 bit), e estou executando no Windows 7 (64 bit). Os tradutores são criados no construtor da classe `MainWindow`, da seguinte forma:

```cpp
// Setup the translation system
QTranslator *pPortuguese = new QTranslator(this);
QString sPortuguese = QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath().replace(".exe", "_pt_BR.qm");
if(pPortuguese->load(sPortuguese))
    m_mpTranslators.insert(map<QString, QTranslator*>::value_type(QString("pt_BR"), pPortuguese));
else
    qWarning() << "Portuguese translation file not found";

QTranslator *pEnglish = new QTranslator(this);
QString sEnglish = QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath().replace(".exe", "_en_UK.qm");
if(pEnglish->load(sEnglish))
    m_mpTranslators.insert(map<QString, QTranslator*>::value_type(QString("en_UK"), pEnglish));
else
    qWarning() << "English translation file not found";
```

O atributo m_mpTranslators é um mapa simples que relaciona a string do locale com o tradutor: `std::map<QString, QTranslator*> m_mpTranslators;`

Comment: Que versão do QT você usa, e de onde vem o _Translator_? Eu vejo `mpTranslators`, mas aonde e como essa variável recebe o _Translator_?

Comment: Desculpe @bigown. Já corrigi. :)

Comment: @MarcosZolnowski, eu editei a pergunta pra incluir as informações que você solicitou. Como eu disse, as traduções funcionam corretamente para a interface gráfica. Não funcionam apenas para os textos extraídos via chamada QApplication::tr().

Comment: Downvote por não escrever Qt seria pior @bigown :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O problema realmente decorreu de uma falha (erro meu, sorry!) na atualização dos arquivos de tradução (*.qm) no diretório de destino do build. No arquivo .pro não haviam instruções para a cópia automatizada das traduções para os diretórios de destino, e por isso os testes utilizavam uma versão anterior das traduções (que eu havia manualmente copiado, provavelmente). Isso resultou na incorreta exibição dos textos independentemente do contexto utilizado.

Para solucionar o problema *definitivamente*, eu alterei o arquivo .pro para incluir nas configurações de release e debug a cópia automatizada dos arquivos para os diretórios *corretos*:

```pro
. . .

copyfiles.commands += @echo Copying translation files... &

# Configurações para Windows
win32{

    . . .

    # Troca '/' por '\' nos diretórios de origem e destino
    SOURCE_WIN = $${PWD}
    SOURCE_WIN ~= s,/,\\,g
    TARGET_WIN = $${OUT_PWD}
    TARGET_WIN ~= s,/,\\,g

    debug_and_release {
        CONFIG -= debug_and_release
        CONFIG += debug_and_release
    }

    # Configurações de debug
    CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
        CONFIG -= debug release
        CONFIG += debug

        . . .

        copyfiles.commands += @call copy $${SOURCE_WIN}\\*.qm $${TARGET_WIN}\\debug\\
    }

    # Configurações de release
    CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
        CONFIG -= debug release
        CONFIG += release

        . . .

        copyfiles.commands += @call copy $${SOURCE_WIN}\\*.qm $${TARGET_WIN}\\release\\
    }

}

# Inclui os comandos de cópia das traduções na execução do QMake
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += copyfiles
POST_TARGETDEPS += copyfiles

. . .
```

Comment: Eu não esperava por isso, mas o único indicador é a data de modificação do arquivo, porque não se pode simplesmente abrir o arquivo no editor de texto.

Comment: Por favor, marque a resposta para o seu problema (embora tenha sido você mesmo que postou). Isso permitirá que todos saibam que seu problema foi resolvido sem precisar ler o tópico.

Comment: @RenatoUtsch: Obrigado pela dica. Já fiz como sugerido.

Answer (score 4):

Eu uso uma versão mais antiga, mas pelo que entendi, a chamada do `TR` na sua classe está errada.

A documentação fala que se sua classe não é sub-classe de `QObject`, use `TR` de `QCoreApplication`:

> If the quoted text is not in a member function of a QObject subclass,
>   use either the tr() function of an appropriate class, or the
>   QCoreApplication::translate() function directly

A questão é: **de que jeito você chama ela?**
Abaixo o exemplo da documentação:

```c
 qApp->translate("LoginWidget", "Password:"),
             logwid);
```

Acho interessante que este exemplo acima deve usar uma instancia de `QApplication`, e ele usa `translate` em vez de `TR`.

Comment: Acabei de fazer um teste. Estava até bastante esperançoso porque a sua resposta faz bastante sentido. Troquei todas as chamadas de QApplication::tr() para qApp->translate() com um contexto diferente (ficou assim, por exemplo: qApp->translate("EmotionData", "Aperture of Left Eye"), com o contexto "EmotionData"). Retraduzi algumas frases pra teste (cheguei até a apagar os arquivos .qm e recompilar tudo), e infelizmente não funcionou.

Comment: Pode dizer se chamando `qApp->translate("EmotionData", "Aperture of Left Eye")` logo depois `UpdateUI()` funciona? Pode ser que você tenha que cadastrar manualmente os termos, ou ele quer outro contexto. Mas sabendo se funciona logo após a chamada, já ajuda bastante a entender o problema.

Comment: Fiz o teste com QString s = qApp->translate("EmotionData", "Aperture of Left Eye"); qDebug() << "s = " << s; logo depois da chamada de UpdateUI(). O resultado é sempre em inglês (o que está no código), independentemente do locale.

Comment: Aliás, o que você quis dizer com "cadastrar manualmente os termos"? :)

Comment: Manualmente seria editar manualmente os arquivos *.TS (que não recomendo), melhor usar a técnica do `QT_TR_NOOP()`. Pois é, deveria ter vindo o texto certo nesse teste, você regerou todos os *.qm?

Comment: Sim, regerei. :( Eu conferi os arquivos .ts e até abri os arquivos .qm gerados pra ver se o conteúdo em pt_br estava lá (e eles aparentemente estão corretos. Mas não acho mesmo que o problema esteja na geração desses arquivos.

Comment: Existe esse contexto "EmotionData"? nos arquivos *.TS? Porque decidi fazer testes de todo tipo, com `TR`, `translate`, direto na MainWindow.ui, e rodando o `lupdate` todas funcionaram.

Comment: Sim, existe. O meu processo é bem padrão: depois de alterar o código (adicionando novas strings, por exemplo), eu exeucuto o lupdate. Vou lá na ferramenta Linguist do Qt e traduzo o que tem de novo. Então, executo o lrelease pra gerar os arquivos .qm. Dai vou no QtCreator e recompilo tudo (pra garantir, rodo qmake de novo antes de fazer o rebuild).

Comment: Também fiz testes usando as mais diversas formas de tradução. O código sempre compila bem, não dá erro de execução, só que não traduz! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11917/discussion-between-marcos-zolnowski-and-luiz-vieira)

Comment: Só pra constar aqui, o problema foi devido a uma falha minha na atualização dos arquivos .qm nos diretórios de destino. Eu adicionei uma resposta com o que eu fiz pra corrigir de vez. Por favor, desculpem pela bobagem. :) De todas as formas, +1 pela ajuda! Obrigado!